# Unable to determine as arff (Reason: java.io.IOException: premature end of line, read Token [EOL], line 1182

Tags: weka, ioexception, arff

I have some data and I am processing it and converting it in a way that it generates a .arff file as follows :

```
............

@attribute murdered_to numeric
@attribute envy.although_it numeric
@attribute vampire_that numeric
@attribute list_without numeric
@attribute award_at numeric
@attribute @% numeric
@attribute the_addict numeric
@attribute the_drag numeric
@attribute card_against numeric
@attribute communications_mainly numeric
@attribute clue_for numeric
@attribute justified.a numeric
@attribute superb_learning numeric
@attribute ford_escape numeric
@attribute a_life-changing numeric
.
.
.
```

This is just a part of the attribute list. I need to open the arff file in weka but it throws the error as mentioned in the subject. The error is pointing to the line :

```
@attribute the_addict numeric
```

I am not able to find the error in the file which is throwing the error.

Comment: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the error is in the line before the one you quoted

```
@attribute @% numeric
```

The name of your attribute is invalid, it must start with an alphabetic character, as specified in the ARFF documentation pointed at by *etov*.

> The format for the @attribute statement is:
>
> ```
> @attribute <attribute-name> <datatype>
> ```
>
> where the  must start with an alphabetic character. If spaces are to be included in the name then the entire name must be quoted.